# Collect list of Integer (List<Integer>) to map with Java 8 Stream API

Tags: arraylist, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I tried to convert a simple `List<Integer>` to a `Map` using Java 8 stream API and got the following compile time error:

```
The method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? 
extends U>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments 
(Function<Object,Object>, boolean)
```

My code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> m_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

m_list.add(1);
m_list.add(2);
m_list.add(3);
m_list.add(4);

Map<Integer, Boolean> m_map = m_list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), true));
```

I also tried the second method below but got the same error.

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> m_map = m_list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Integer::intValue, true));
```

What is the correct way to do this using Java 8 stream API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing a `boolean` for the value mapper. You should pass a `Function<Integer,Boolean>`.

It should be:

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> m_map = m_list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), e -> true));
```